# Rotating over 360 degrees

Tags: math, geometry, angle

I have a polygon that I want to rotate around over 360 degrees but still keeping track of the full rounds.

I have the angle of the finger defined as variable angle and i know the angle of the mob I am rotating, but after every full turn the angle just resets because the angle between touch point and mob goes from 360 to 0 or vice versa.

How can I get around this?

current code:

```
double rotation = angle - lastAngle;
selectedMob.rotate((float) (rotation));
```

where angle is the angle between touch point and mob, lastAngle is angle before this.

method rotate just adds the rotation to the current angle like this:

```
public void rotate(float angle) {
    this.angle += angle;
}
```

angle is defined as

```
                double rads = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                double angle = Math.toDegrees(rads);
```

and then I adjust the angle so it starts from 0 at up but I make sure it goes from 0 to 360

debug:

```
09-13 00:03:53.708: V/GameActivity(23389): updating frame
09-13 00:03:53.708: V/GameActivity(23389): checked for all mobs
09-13 00:03:53.825: V/GameActivity(23389): Angle of finger is 360.0
09-13 00:03:53.825: V/GameActivity(23389): Angle of mob is 344.94818
09-13 00:03:53.825: V/GameActivity(23389): Last angle is 359.56921278299137
09-13 00:03:53.825: V/GameActivity(23389): Rotation will be 0.43078721700862843
09-13 00:03:53.825: V/GameActivity(23389): ****************
09-13 00:03:53.825: V/GameActivity(23389): updating frame
09-13 00:03:53.825: V/GameActivity(23389): checked for all mobs
09-13 00:03:54.137: V/GameActivity(23389): Angle of finger is 0.4275725068334077
09-13 00:03:54.137: V/GameActivity(23389): Angle of mob is 345.37897
09-13 00:03:54.137: V/GameActivity(23389): Last angle is 360.0
09-13 00:03:54.137: V/GameActivity(23389): Rotation will be -359.5724274931666
09-13 00:03:54.137: V/GameActivity(23389): ****************
```

Comment: Add another variable to keep track of the full rotations.

Comment: Which of the angles is reset? How do you calculate `angle`?

Comment: @duffymo I dont actually want to do that, I actually want the angle to go from 360 to 361, 362...

Comment: @NicoSchertler mobs angle goes back to 0 or so as the rotation from 0 to 360 is like -360 or vice versa

Comment: `this.angle += angle;` looks like this does not reset the angle back to 0, it should already do what you want. Maybe it's a display error?

Comment: @TaZ my language probably were confusing, below you can see answer to the problem also I added debug output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the current angle to be in the same range as `lastAngle`:

```
while(Math.Abs(angle - lastAngle) > 180)
    angle += (angle > lastAngle ? -360 : 360);
```

Comment: And it works! While loop looks pretty scary in my eyes tho :e Thank you very much!

Comment: Theoretically, `if` would be sufficient. `while` works for all cases.

Comment: boo? What happened to Modulo?

Comment: How could modulo help us here? I am getting stackoverflow in my brains when thinking about it :(